# PHP array merge multiple indexed array

Tags: php

I am Having array Like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title1] => SDSF
            [lat2] => SDDS
            [lng3] => SDSDSD
            [description4] => SDSD
            [category5] => SDSFFG
        )    

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => dsfg
        [lat] => sdsd
        [lng] => sd
        [description] => er
        [category] => sddsdsd
    )
 )
```

I am struggling to merge the array

I am expecting my array to be like this

```
Array
        (
            [title1] => SDSF
            [lat2] => SDDS
            [lng3] => SDSDSD
            [description4] => SDSD
            [category5] => SDSFFG
            [title] => dsfg
            [lat] => sdsd
            [lng] => sd
            [description] => er
            [category] => sddsdsd
        )
```

Any help regarding this Please

Comment: array_merge($array[0],$array[1]);

Comment: Use: $output = $array1 + $array2;

Comment: @sumit this is not a duplicate , check the array structure also only array_merge will not work

Comment: thanks for help
I have already tried that
I got output like this
Array
(
    [title1] => SDSF
    [lat2] => SDDS
    [lng3] => SDSDSD
    [description4] => SDSD
    [category5] => SDSFFG
)

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop for lopping around your main/root array and use **[array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**

working code ....

```
    <?php
$root =array
(
    '0' => array
        (
            'title1' => 'SDSF',
            'lat2' => 'SDDS',
            'lng3' => 'SDSDSD',
            'description4' => 'SDSD',
            'category5' => 'SDSFFG'
        ) ,   

'1' => array
    (
        'title' => 'dsfg',
        'lat' => 'sdsd',
        'lng' => 'sd',
        'description' => 'er',
        'category' => 'sddsdsd'
    )

);
$result = array();
foreach($root as $child_array)
{
    $result = array_merge($result,$child_array);
}
print_r($result);


    ?>
```

***else do...***

```
print_r(array_merge($root[0],$root[1]));
```

***else do...***

```
print_r($root[0]+$root[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the solution

Comment: accept the solution so others can get help from here in future

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you.

```
$a = array(
    'title1' => 'SDSF',
    'lat2' => 'SDDS',
    'lng3' => 'SDSDSD',
    'description4' => 'SDSD',
    'category5' => 'SDSFFG'
    );
$b = array(
    'title' => 'dsfg',
    'lat' => 'sdsd',
    'lng' => 'sd',
    'description' => 'er',
    'category' => 'sddsdsd'
    );
$c = $a + $b;
print_r($c);
```

You will get exact output what you want.

Comment: Thanks Dekts got a solution

Comment: You have to do some googling dear. you are near of your answer so do littel hard work.